# Unable to configure mobile with Jmeter

Tags: performance, mobile, jmeter

I want to perform load test on my mobile app using Jmeter but I am facing issues in configuring my mobile phone. I have installed Jmeter and added recording template in it and set the port no of HTTP Test script recorder to 8080. NOw I installed the certificate in my mobile device and set the proxy settings of my device by giving IP and port no. But after setting proxy I am unable to access the internet. My app is not working due to loss of internet and when I remove proxy it starts working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you start proxy.

Ensure that your Mobile sees your machine (you're in the same network)

If your application uses https you need to add to your mobile root authorities the jmeter generated certificate located in jmeter/bin folder and generated the first time you start Recorder.

Finally If you’re under android then see this:

- [Jmeter Root certification installer for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842541/jmeter-root-certification-installer-for-android/52264347#52264347)

Comment: I have installed the certificate generated by Jmeter in my device but still facing the issue

Comment: Did you start proxy ? What is the mobile you're using Android or IOS ? which version ?

Comment: I have tried both ios and android devices and yes I set the proxy in devices but still not working

Comment: Android version 7 nauget

Comment: ok, then check my answer in the link I provided in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842541/jmeter-root-certification-installer-for-android/52264347#52264347 particularly the part the requires modifying application

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to connect JMeter version 4 to a mobile app on an android device. What solved my issue was to turn off the Windows 10 firewall. I did not think this would be an issue as the mobile device connected to the wifi hotspot I created on my laptop. But as soon as you setup a manual proxy on the android device it got blocked. The firewall was blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the certificate by following the steps below. I was also not able to connect to internet after installing the certificate. The mistake made by was, I was not giving .crt extension when installing the certificate. Once the extension was given, I was able to make connection to jmeter and also use the app with internet.

1. Import the certificate to the phone.
2. Click on the imported certifcate.
3. In the certificate name section give any name of your choice and ensure the extension .crt is given.